# Font awesome not working on iOS7

Tags: ios, ios7, mobile-safari, font-awesome, cdn

Having a problem with iOS7 not displaying FontAwesome, even though I have FontAwesome pulled in from a CDN:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

However, the fonts this file is pulling in, it is looking for locally:

```
@font-face{font-family:'FontAwesome';
src:url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eotv=4.5.0');
src:url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.5.0') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.5.0') format('woff2'),
url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.5.0') format('woff'),
url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.5.0') format('truetype'),
url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.5.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
```

It is looking here:

```
http://<<our-domain>>fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.5.0#fontawesomeregular
```

When it should be looking for them on the CDN.

Thanks in advance,

Aaron

Answer (score 0):

Hi had a similar problem but with glyphicon, it turned out to be a .woff2 extension issue as the iOS browsers doesn't appear to support it. I solved it by removing all .woff2 extension files and replace them with the .woff ones.

Comment: It turned out our problem was due to the fact that the font wasn't hosted locally